# Troubleshooting a Django collectstatic Error After Upgrading to Version 4.2

Tags: django, collectstatic

I'm encountering an issue with the collectstatic command, which persisted until I upgraded Django to version 4.2. When I execute ./manage.py collectstatic, it throws an error that says, `my_path/myfile.map' could not be found with <project.assets.CustomStorage object at 0x7f1af8be4370>` and I'm struggling to understand the cause.

In my settings.py file, I've configured the STORAGES dictionary as follows:

`STORAGES["staticfiles"] = {"BACKEND": "project.assets.CustomStorage"}`

Where CustomStorage is a custom class defined as:

```
class CustomStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.AWS_ASSETS_BUCKET_FOLDER
    querystring_auth = False
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_ASSETS_BUCKET_NAME
```

Would you be able to assist me in resolving this issue?